# Not resulting the way I want it to

Tags: python

```
operator = input("Please select one option: add/subtract/multiply/divide: ")
if operator != "add" or operator != "subtract" or operator != "multiply" or operator != "divide":
    print("The option you chose (" + operator + ") is not valid\nPlease try this program again.")
    sys.exit()
```

Result:

```
Please select one option: add/subtract/multiply/divide: add                                                                                                                                 
The option you chose (add) is not valid                                                                                                                                                     
Please try this program again.
```

Comment: Think about it: if you input `"add"`, then `operator != "add"` will be `False`, but `operator != "subtract"` will be `True`, `operator != "multiply"` will also be `True`, so as `operator != "divide"`. You probably need to rethink the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing how boolean algebra works.

```py
operator != "add" or operator != "subtract" or operator != "multiply" or operator != "divide"
```

This will return true if operator **is not** *either of* add/subtract/multiply/divide.

So when you enter `add`, `operator != "add"` returns false, but the next one - `operator != "subtract"` returns true. Since it is an `or` operator, only **one** of all the expressions need to return true, for the whole expression to return true.

You should instead do-

```py
operator != "add" and operator != "subtract" and operator != "multiply" and operator != "divide"
```

In simple english, that reads "return true if `operator` is **none of** add/subtract/multiply/divide"

Or more simply, using the `in` operator-

```py
operator not in ["add", "subtract", "multiply", "divide"]
```

Which in simple english, reads "return true if operator **is not an element in the list**  `["add", "subtract", "multiply", "divide"]`"